# htaccess files in sub folders

Tags: apache, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

I have a development environment with a folder structure like;

> /server/project1
>
> /server/project2
>
> /server/root

Within /server I have a htaccess file which rewrites everything coming from dev.* to /server/root like so;

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
   RewriteEngine on

   RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^dev [NC]
   RewriteRule ^(.*)$ root/$1 [L,QSA]

</IfModule>
```

This works, but it's failing when a htaccess with rewrite rules exists in say /server/project1 when a URL is used similar to dev.local.com/project1

I'd like it to ignore the htaccess file in /server/project1 and always be directed to /root how can I do this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have rules in a subdirectory, those rules will always have precedence over rules in parent directories. In apache 2.2, the best you can do is use the [`RewriteOptions`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions) to inherit rules from a parent directory **after** the rules in subdirectory:

```
RewriteOptions inherit
```

Not sure if that's going to help, depending on the rules that you're using.

In apache 2.4, the [`RewriteOptions`](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/mod/mod_rewrite.html#rewriteoptions) directive has a few more options. You have the "InheritBefore" option now to stick rules in the parent directory **before** the rules in the current subdirectory.

Your only other option is to setup your vhost such that `dev` is in its own vhost with the document root in `/root/`.

Comment: I was expecting rules to cascade downwards rather than upwards, if I don't want to modify all of the htaccess files in 'sub folders' is vhost the only way to go?

Comment: @Alex it's probably the most straightforward way to do it.