# Disable hotlink protection in subfolder with .htaccess

Tags: apache, .htaccess

Searched but can't find a working answer/solution. I am using ReWriteCond/Rule to disable hotlinking to files on my site. However I have one subfolder that I want to disable the hotlink protection, but am having no joy.

I am using in the main directory (`example.com`) to block all hotlink and all works fine.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.example.com$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp|mp4)$ - [F,NC]
```

I have another directory `example.com/free` that I WANT to allow hotlinking of my mp4 files, so am using

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.example.com$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(jpg|jpeg|gif|png|bmp)$ - [F,NC]
```

But I am still unable to download or hotlink to the mp4's in the folder.

Everything I reads says it should work but obviously I am doing something wrong, just not sure what.

For clarification, I am using a download php script to build the URI for downloading and it works fine on NON-hotlink protected files (as tested when I disable the hotlink protection in .htaccess)

Comment: Try and add `RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !^/free/` to specifically demand the requested path to not start with that folder name.

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that when you access a file in the `/free` folder, the .htaccess file in the root folder is still being applied and is disallowing hotlinks to .mp4 files.

For the rule in the .htaccess file in the `/free` folder where you *do* want to allow .mp4 files, specify only mp4 files and remove the 'F' flag so it becomes:

```
RewriteCond %{HTTP_REFERER} !^https://www.example.com$      [NC]
RewriteRule .*\.(mp4)$ - [NC]
```

This should allow only mp4 files from referrers that are not https://www.example.com.

Comment: Don't know how I missed the "F" flag, but tried that and achieved the same results. The file is not downloaded/hotlinked.
I am not sure on the deny/allow process here. If a set of directives is established in a root level .htaccess file, do the rules in a subfolder .htaccess keep the root .htaccess directives and append to them or do the subfolder ,htaccess directives completely replace the root level directives?

Comment: @MadDogDean You said you are using a PHP script to create the download URL. Does that mean the URL for the .mp4 file actually ends with .php? If so, you'll have to change mp4 to php in the subfolder RewriteRule.

Comment: [.htaccess subfolder priority is described here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/20926051/378779)